# ntlm proxy authentication rcurl problem

Tags: r, proxy, ntlm, rcurl

i'm behind an ntlm proxy server and i can't set the rcurl options correctly for it to work.
Apparently curl woks fine with the correct settings which are:

```
--proxy-ntlm 
--proxy_user <...>
--proxy <...>
```

but i don't know how to pass all these options correctly from R.

I've got as far as:

```
>curl = getCurlHandle()
>curlSetOpt( .opts = list(proxy="...:...",proxyuserpwd="...:...",proxyauth="ntlm"),curl = curl)
>getURL("http://www.omegahat.org", curl = curl)
```

but  this still doesn't seem to do the trick.

thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks reasonable, but there are a few gotchas to watch out for.

Your username probably needs the domain too, i.e., `mydomain\\myusername:mypassword`.

All `\`s need escaping, including those in your password.

If all else fails, try connecting on a different port.

Comment: thanks, this helped
i alse had to change httpauth to proxyauth

Comment: @KarolPal Would you provide the final solution?